# Change process name in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to change the name of a currently executing process in C# (or .NET in general)? I believe it isn't possible, but my co-worker is trying to solve a problem under the assumption that it is.

Comment: The ol' advice for a friend gag, eh?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but said co-worker is trying to solve an actual problem. I'm not trying to create a malware program with this. Actualy, this is one of the reasons why I think it isn't possible because I'd consider it a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No it is not possible to change the name of the currently executing process.  Process names are defined by the name file which was loaded into the operating system for execution at the time execution began.   You cannot change this at a later point.  This is true for C#, managed and native code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible... al least under linux.
Using this:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("libc")]
// Linux  
private static extern int prctl (int option, byte[] arg2, IntPtr arg3, IntPtr arg4, IntPtr arg5);
```

I suppose a dll exists under windows that works in the same way :-)

Comment: Can you please provide the sample of its usage?

Answer (score 0):

Process name in Windows is derived from the EXE used to run the file. If it's your process, you could copy your EXE to a temporary folder with a new name, and then run it from there...

This assumes that it'd be running in the same context, etc.