# Updating a Process Name While Running

Tags: c#, maf

I am using [MAF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to load up addins for my application and leveraging the Token.Activate overload that loads the addin into its own process.  This loads one `AddInProcess.exe` for each addin in my system. Is there anything I can do to have Task Manager reflect that this process is coming from my application and the addin to which corresponds?

I do have the PID in my hand, so I was trying to determine if there is a Win32 API that I could call that could update the process name, but everything I have read seems to indicate there is no way to update a process name.  Have I missed something?

Note: I do maintain a list of addins loaded in my application, so I can surface all of this in my application, but it would be nice to have Task Manager show a little more information.

Comment: The process tree should be maintained (but that's probably only visible to something like sysinternals procviewer); I assume you're looking for complete transparency without using an additional tool? -- EDIT: May be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349155/how-to-specify-addin-process-names & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914183/give-maf-plugin-which-run-as-separate-process-a-custom-name

Comment: You cant change the process name once its loaded an running. Task Manager uses the `ProcessName` property without the extension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change process name in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402824/change-process-name-in-c)